# Infopath forms issue with browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

All my `InfoPath` forms are opening in Chrome but one form is not opening in Internet Explorer.

Is there any method to fix this?

Comment: What is the version of your Internet Explorer ? i mean IE10, IE11 ?

Comment: Its Internet explorer 11

Answer (score 1):

I was also having issue with IE11 and InfoPath forms.
You can try following steps that helped me to resolved this issue.

In your browser
GoTO Tools >> Compatibility View Settings

Here Add your website.

Restart your browser

Done

(OR refer this article : http://imrazarajwani.blogspot.in/2013/12/error-object-doesnt-support-property-or.html)

Comment: this is not working for me..